# SQLite で複数のカラムを条件として抽出する方法

Tags: sqlite

以下のようなテーブルで、pkeyとIDが両方とも合致する条件として抽出したいです。
IDやNameは重複する可能性があります。
合致する条件はリストで任意に複数が与えられます。

```
CREATE TABLE "Tbl_Dev" (
    "pkey"  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "ID"    TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unkown',
    PRIMARY KEY("pkey" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

仮のデータとして以下のようにしました。

```
pkey|ID|Name
1|0|Unkown1
2|0|Unkown2
3|0|Unkown3
4|0|Unkown4
```

試したSELECT文

```
SELECT pkey,ID 
FROM Tbl_Dev 
WHERE （pkey, ID)
IN (('1','0'),('2','0'))
```

エラーメッセージ

```
Execution finished with errors
Result: row value misused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決された方法ではインデックスが効かず、pkeyやIDがINTEGER型の場合は暗黙の型変換が発生します。
インデックスを有効にしたい場合は副問い合わせでダミー表を作成して結合する方法もあります。
正直なところ可読性は下がりますので、インデックスの有無やレコード数、要求速度に合わせて対応方法を選択するのが良いと思います。

[SO本家の類似回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365048)

```
-- 疑似テーブル作成
with Tbl_Dev as (
    select 1 pkey, 0 ID, 'Unkown1' Name union all
    select 2 pkey, 0 ID, 'Unkown2' Name union all
    select 3 pkey, 0 ID, 'Unkown3' Name union all
    select 4 pkey, 0 ID, 'Unkown4' Name)
-- サンプルSQL
select t.*
from   Tbl_Dev as t
-- (pkey, ID) in (('1','0'),('2','0')) の代用テーブル結合
join  (select 1 pkey, 0 ID union all
       select 2 pkey, 0 ID) as lookup
on     t.pkey = lookup.pkey
and    t.ID   = lookup.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

質問内容にあるSELECT文は、MySQLなどでは機能するそうですがSQLiteでは未サポートのようです。
参考URLに解決策がありました。
このようにIN句に使用する一次リストを作成します。

```
ID_list = [0,0]
Key_list = [1,2]
W_list = [f'{k}_{id}' for k,id in zip(Key_list,ID_list)]
```

SELECT文は以下のようになります。

```
SELECT ID, name
FROM Tbl_Dev AS t
WHERE t.pkey || '_' || t.ID
IN ('1_0','2_0')
```

参考
[SQL Search Query with multiple columns needs to edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387585/sql-search-query-with-multiple-columns-needs-to-edited/14388639#14388639)

Answer (score 0):

適切かどうかわからないけど、
一度andを使ってwhere分を分けてやったら、
エラーは発生しません。

```sql
SELECT pkey,ID 
FROM Tbl_Dev 
WHERE pkey
IN (('1'))
and pkey
IN (('2'))
and ID
IN (('2'))
and ID
IN (('0'))
```